# Mailer method returns unexpected ActionMailer::Base::NullMail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I am new to Rubyand also not good at OOP. I have a class like this

```
class Workflow::Mailer < ActionMailer::Base
    def unapproved_remind_mail(args)
        return [
            {
                "uid": "1060_424652",
                "noticecd": "A002",
                "ref_url": "",
                "title": "",
                "content": ""
            },
            {
                "uid": "1060_403595",
                "noticecd": "A002",
                "ref_url": "",
                "title": "",
                "content": ""
            }
        ].to_json
    end

    def self.send_unapproved_remind_mails(args)
        args = args.dup
        sm_body = unapproved_remind_mail(args)
        Rails.logger.fatal("sm_body: #{sm_body}")
    end
end
```

when I call function `Workflow::Mailer.send_unapproved_remind_mails` it logs `sm_body: #<ActionMailer::Base::NullMail:0x000055f289ff5ad8>` instead of the hash object. Is there anyway to fix this?

**Edit**: I also want to call a private method inside unapproved_remind_mail

Comment: Why is `send_unapproved_remind_mails` a class method? [Action Mailer](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) works by defining _instance methods_ that typically call [`mail`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html#method-i-mail). Helper methods that don't send email are supposed to be private. It's much easier if you follow the conventions.

Comment: Can you explain why are using ActionMailer that way? You mentioned some API / notification in a now deleted comment. It would be helpful to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: In `unapproved_remind_mail` I try to prepare the content for both the email and a notification's body which will be passed to an API later. In `self.send_unapproved_remind_mails`, I tried to deliver both the email and call the api to send the notification's body. @Stefan

Comment: At first the `unapproved_remind_mail` was only used for preparing mail object to be sent, but I tried to modify it so that I can do other things. I guess it is hard in Ruby

Answer (score 1):

app/mailers/workflow/mailer.rb

```
class Workflow::Mailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "from@example.com"
  # layout 'mailer'

  def send_unapproved_remind_mails(args)
    @sm_body = unapproved_remind_mail(args)
    Rails.logger.fatal("sm_body: #{@sm_body}")

    mail(
      subject: "Email Subject",
      to: "to@example.com"
    )
  end

  private

  def unapproved_remind_mail(args)  # args param should be used in the method body, otherwise define it as parameterless method
    return [
      {
        "uid": "1060_424652",
        "noticecd": "A002",
        "ref_url": "",
        "title": "",
        "content": ""
      },
      {
        "uid": "1060_403595",
        "noticecd": "A002",
        "ref_url": "",
        "title": "",
        "content": ""
      }
    ].to_json
  end
end
```

app/views/workflow/mailer/send_unapproved_remind_mails.html.erb

```
// your email body...
```

**Output**:

```
sm_body: [{"uid":"1060_424652","noticecd":"A002","ref_url":"","title":"","content":""},{"uid":"1060_403595","noticecd":"A002","ref_url":"","title":"","content":""}]
  Rendering workflow/mailer/send_unapproved_remind_mails.html.erb
  Rendered workflow/mailer/send_unapproved_remind_mails.html.erb (Duration: 1.0ms | Allocations: 182)
Workflow::Mailer#send_unapproved_remind_mails: processed outbound mail in 62.7ms
#<Mail::Message:97340, Multipart: false, Headers: <From: from@example.com>, <To: to@example.com>, <Subject: Email Subject>, <Mime-Version: 1.0>, <Content-Type: text/html>>
```

Comment: I want to use private method inside unapproved_remind_mail, what should I do?

Comment: @ManjunathP now `Workflow::Mailer.send_unapproved_remind_mails` will return a `ActionMailer::Base::NullMail` instance.

Comment: I have edit my answer to define it as private method and tested the code too.

Answer (score 1):

A Rails mailer defines instance methods which generate the email by calling [`mail`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html#method-i-mail), e.g.:

```rb
# app/mailers/workflow_mailer.rb

class WorkflowMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def unapproved_remind_mail(address)
    mail(to: address)
  end
end
```

You typically have a *view* that returns the email body:

```rb
# app/views/workflow_mailer.text.erb

Hello, this is your reminder.
```

To send the email, you call [`deliver_now`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/MessageDelivery.html#method-i-deliver_now) / [`deliver_later`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/MessageDelivery.html#method-i-deliver_later):

```rb
WorkflowMailer.unapproved_remind_mail('foo@example.com').deliver_now
```

Note that `unapproved_remind_mail` is called in a very unusual way: despite being an instance method, you call the method on the class itself. This is something Rails came up with to ... make things easier I suppose.

To fetch additional data for the email body from another method, you can add a private helper and assign its result to an instance method, e.g.:

```rb
class WorkflowMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def unapproved_remind_mail(address)
    @json_data = json_data
    mail(to: address)
  end

  private

  def json_data
    { foo: 123 }.to_json
  end
end
```

Which can be used in the view:

```rb
# app/views/workflow_mailer.text.erb

Hello, this is your reminder.

<%= @json_data %>
```